# magento quickstart theme in local server but while login using admin front end it will redirecting to anothe page

Tags: magento

I have purchased “Flipshop – Multipurpose Responsive Magento Theme” and i have installed the quickstart theme in local server but while login using admin front end it will redirecting to this page http://dev.ytcvn.com/ytc_templates/magento/sm-flipshop/.
 i have changed the base url and secure url on ‘core_config_data’ table but redirecting to http://dev.ytcvn.com/ytc_templates/magento/sm-flipshop/.

Answer (score 0):

Flush all caches using admin panel.

Go to root/var folder and ensure you remove cache/ and full_page_cache/

If that doesn't work please post your log tail -500 inside root/var/log/exception.log or root/var/reports/4353reportnumber.